# conditional ManualValidation step in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using the Azure DevOps `ManualValidation` task, can the job run conditionally, based on variables defined earlier in the pipeline?

The job accepts an `enabled` parameter, but it seems this must be hard-coded to true or false.

```
- stage: Approve_${{ targetPath.stageName }}_${{ parameters.planEnvironment }}
  jobs:
    - job: waitForValidation
      displayName: Wait for external validation
      pool: server
      timeoutInMinutes: ${{ parameters.timeoutInMinutes }}
      steps:
        - task: ManualValidation@0
          environment: development ## environment not accepted here
          #enabled: $[destroy] ## Unexpected value '$[destroy]'",
          #enabled: $(destroy) ## fails - syntax error (does not like this to be a var)
          # manually setting true/false works
          #enabled: true
          #enabled: false
          inputs:
            notifyUsers: |
              alert@test.com
            instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
            onTimeout: 'reject'
```

Comment: Have you checked the following replies? Are they helpful?

Answer (score 2):

`enabled` control option is `boolean` type, which means whether or not to run this step, defaults to 'true'. If you want to use `enabled` control option to condition ManualValidation step, you could check the following syntax:

```
variables:
- name: destroy
  value: true


jobs:  
  - job: waitForValidation
    displayName: Wait for external validation  
    pool: server    
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:   
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      enabled: ${{ variables.destroy }}
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          test@test.com
          example@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'resume'
```

Otherwise can specify the conditions under the steps as @Shayki Abramczyk mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) like in every task:

```
- task: ManualIntervention@8
  inputs:
    instructions: 'test'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['VariableName'], 'VariableValue'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use template parameter conditionals to make the stage, job, or task go away when you don't want it there. That is, when the preprocessing is done on the pipeline code, use conditionals to avoid inserting the item into the expanded yaml file that is actually run when the pipeline runs.

```
- ${{ if ne(parameters.EnvironmentName, 'Dev') }}:
  - stage: Approve_${{ targetPath.stageName }}_${{ parameters.planEnvironment }}
    jobs:
      - job: waitForValidation
        displayName: Wait for external validation
        pool: server
        timeoutInMinutes: ${{ parameters.timeoutInMinutes }}
        steps:
          - task: ManualValidation@0
            environment: development ## environment not accepted here
            inputs:
              notifyUsers: |
                alert@test.com
              instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
              onTimeout: 'reject'
```

This above example is using a pipeline template parameter named EnvironmentName. You have the ability to use *some* variables, as explained in Azure DevOps's [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) documentation (see the "Available in templates?" table column).

Note that any subsequent stages that refer to this stage (or job, if you put the condition on the job) via the `dependsOn` functionality will also need to make that `dependsOn` disappear with the same logic.

More info at the [Conditional Insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) official documentation.